# Safely managing system/local/project Python packages?

Tags: python, gentoo, virtualenv

#### The context

I'm currently running a Gentoo desktop and want to move towards doing proper Python development on my system.

I have tried to install some packages, namely `docker-compose`, through the Gentoo's emerge system. Due to `docker-compose`'s reliance on an older version of the `requests` module, my system updates became hairy and difficult to resolve.

I then switched to `pip` and followed a recommendation to use the `--user` flag for `pip` installs to avoid conflicts with the system-wide tools/libraries. I installed `docker-compose` at this user level and all was well until I added Pipenv to the mix for managing dependencies for individual projects. Pipenv doesn't like the `--user` flag and when set in the `pip.conf` file will refuse to install dependencies into its `virtualenv`.

#### getting to the point...

I would like a way to isolate the different levels of Python packages I need on my system. I would like to leave the system dependencies in place as they have been set by the Gentoo `emerge` tool, have a place to install tools and libraries that I want my primary user to have access to, and finally somewhere that I can store libraries that I need only for a specific project. As my machine has only a single user, I'm not worried so much about sharing the "user" dependencies between users, but ensuring that I can access them from any directory.

I have looked into `virtualenv`s, however it seems that that works better for a "per-project" level rather than a "user" level. From what I can tell, only one `virtualenv` can be active at a time, therefore if I install a tool like `docker-compose` in an always-active `virtualenv` from my home dir, then switch to a new `virtualenv` for a project, I will lose access to the `docker-compose` tool and anything else I have installed into the "user" level `virtualenv`.

In short, what options do I have to manage different "levels" of Python dependencies? What are the best practices to ensuring that I don't tread on my system dependencies from a user level and my user dependencies from a project level? What do you guys do to safely isolate these different levels, if you do it at all?

*This is my first stackexchange post, so please let me know if I can clarify or improve this question. I have tried to do research beforehand, but feel as though I have come up short.*

Comment: Something like `chroot`, namespace containers (`systemd-nspawn`) and/or virtual machines (KVM/qemu) could work, depending on the level of separation you need from the system OS.